# How does Sri Lanka's semi presidential system work ? Who has more power the Prime Minister or the President?

Tags: president, prime-minister, sri-lanka

In france the president is clearly more powerful

Comment: Do you have access to wikipedia? The answer to such questions can be found there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_Sri_Lanka

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP should have done some research before asking

Answer (score 2):

The Sri Lankan president is a powerful position and head of the Sri Lankan government. The second amendment to the constitution changed the role from a ceremonial one to a role with very broad executive power. This was in 1978. The role of the President is modelled on that of the French fifth republic.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_Sri_Lanka))

Comment: just fyi [Why do presidential campaigns in the Philippines begin only 90 days before the election? When was this imposed; what can/can't begin before this date?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/70877/16047) has a bounty expiring in a few days